# C++ list program freeze when i call a function

Tags: c++, list

This code must insert character 'p' before character 'q' how many times 'q' appear in list.

When I call function `insert_before` (`insert_before('q','p')` ) my program freezes. I don't write all the code here. The rest of the program works fine.

```
struct node
{
   char character;
   node* next;
};
node *fisrt , *end;
void insert_before(char val_search,char val_inserted)
{
   node *c,*a;
   c=first;
   do {
      if (c->next->character==val_search)
      {
          a= new node ;
          a->character=val_inserted ;
          a->next=c->next;
          c->next=a;
          c=c->next; 
      }
      else 
          c=c->next; 
   } while (c) ; 
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problems**

Let's suppose that you have a list with a unique element 'q' in it:   `first` and `last` would both point to that single node. And the `next` pointer of the node would be `nullptr`.

When you execute `insert_before()`  you start with `c=first`. So `c` points to this unique node which has `next` being `nullptr`.  Unfortunately this instruction:   `if (c->next->character==val_search)` would dereference the nullptr.  This is undefined behavior and might cause the symptoms that you describe.

If your searched value is not the first element, your code would work in principle.  Unfortunately, after having inserted the element, you continue to loop: you'd then loop at the new element, and the condition would be true again, so that you will insert again a new element and so on, endlessly looping until your list exhausts all the memory.  This also would cause freeze. 
By the way, do you really want to insert 'p' before all the 'q's in the list ?

**First correction**

Just correct the loop, being more careful:

```
void insert_before(char val_search,char val_inserted)
{
   node *c,*a;
   for (c=first; c && c->next; c=c->next) {
      if (c->next->character==val_search)
      {
          a= new node ;
          a->character=val_inserted ;
          a->next=c->next;
          c->next=a;
          c=a;
      }
   }  
}
```

Note that this code, exactly as your code, doesn't handle properly the insertion in front of the list.

**Second fix:**

To be able to insert in front, you need something like this:

```
void insert_before(char val_search,char val_inserted)
{
   node *c,*a, *prev=nullptr;
   for (c=first; c ; prev=c, c=c->next) {
      if (c->character==val_search)
      {
          a= new node ;
          a->character=val_inserted ;
          a->next=c;
          if (prev)
             prev->next=a;
          else first=a;
      }
   }  
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/XHGw9A)

Answer (score 1):

When you find the value `p`, you insert a new entry *before* the found entry.

This means, next time you will find the same entry again and insert another new entry *before* the found entry

```
+---+  +---+
| x |->| p |
+---+  +---+
  c
```

will become

```
+---+  +---+  +---+
| x |->| q |->| p |
+---+  +---+  +---+
         c
```

and then it will become

```
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
| x |->| q |->| q |->| p |
+---+  +---+  +---+  +---+
                c
```

and so on.

Because this will never end (until you run out of memory), the program appears to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Inside if {}, change c=c->next to c=a->next.

Comment: the program still freeze

Comment: The change I told you to make was to solve the obvious bug illustrated by @Olaf Dietsche. If the code freezes still, there is some other bug. Unfortunately you did not provide additional code which contains the other bugs. I'd say I've answered your question based on what you posted. For the other bugs, please use a debugger or post more code